# Node js App stoping When Console is closed

Tags: node.js, express

Am new to node , created my first express based app and deployed in my development server.

```
node app.js
```

given above command no errors and working properly , after logoff my putty application seems to be stopped ,how can i solve this issue .

- Is there any other way for running node apps.

Comment: create it as a `service `

Comment: @KalaiselvanA can you explain , it will be more helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a PM2 module and start your application using PM2.

npm install pm2 -g

pm2 start app.js --name "Your App name"

To see your app

pm2 list

Answer (score 2):

Install forever  using **npm install forever -g**

then use this command

```
forever start app.js
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Answer (score 1):

That's because your session will be terminated. All you need is a session handler. It depends on your OS. You can use screenrc on linux -> https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Screen/.

Answer (score 1):

Run NodeJS as a Service on Ubuntu

> With Node you can write very fast JavaScript programs serverside. It's pretty easy to install Node, code your program, and run it. But > how do you make it run nicely in the background like a true server

```
Go to `/etc/init/`
$ sudo nano yourapp.conf`
Paste **script.conf**
$ sudo start yourapp`
```

And when you wanna kill the process `$ sudo stop yourapp`

```
  description "node.js server"
  author      "your name"

  # used to be: start on startup
  # until we found some mounts weren't ready yet while booting

  start on started mountall
  stop on shutdown

  # automatically respawn

  respawn
  respawn limit 99 5

 script

        export HOME="/root"
        exec /usr/bin/nodejs /path/to/yourapp.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1

 end script

 post-start script

   # optionally put a script here that will notifiy you node has (re)started
   # /root/bin/hoptoad.sh "node.js has started!"

 end script
```

for further reference https://gist.github.com/jobsamuel/6d6095d52228461f3c53

Comment: similar way for UNIX systems also

Comment: sorry, I don't have experience with UNIX systems. paths may be different but similar way